# eventListner function keeps firing even after the object it is listening on is destroyed

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Here is the code that I'm trying to understand.

```
async function foo(){
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  
  page.on('response',callBackFunction);
  
  await page.goto('http://stackoverflow.com');

  return 'done';
}

function callBackFunction(){
  console.log('response received');
}

foo().then(x=>console.log(x));
```

The above code will print out multiple `response received` then once `foo` returns and the promise is resolved, `done` will be printed out, until this point everything is working as expected.

However, the problem that I don't understand is that after `done` I keep seeing `response received`.

From my understanding, variables like `puppeteer` `browser` `page` that are defined inside `foo` function will get destroyed after `foo` returns.

If that's true, then, how come `callBackFunction` is still being called after function `foo` already finished?

**Edit:**

If the variables get destroyed and the objects they're pointing to don't, then, what is preventing garbage collector from destroying these objects too, is it the fact that there is a listener on `page` or is it that the `puppeteer` object is still referencing the browser which has not been closed yet?

Comment: The variables get destroyed, the objects they point to don't.

Comment: @Barmar If the variables get destroyed and the objects they're pointing to don't, then, what is preventing garbage collector from destroying these objects too, is it the fact that there is a listener on `page` or is it that the `puppeteer` object is still referencing the browser which has not been closed yet?

Comment: Until the browser is closed, it has references to these objects.